# Question about inverse system and inverse limit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory

Let $R_m=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m]$ be the ring of polynomials. Define $g_{mn}:R_m \to R_n$ by
\begin{equation}
g_{mn}(x_{i})=\begin{cases}
x_i,&i<n \\
x_n,& n\leq i \leq m,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
extended algebraically. The pair $(R_n,g_{mn})$ gives us an inverse system (defined over $\mathbb{N})$. Consider
\begin{equation}
x=(x_1,2x_1-x_2,2x_1-2x_2+x_3,2x_1-2x_2+2x_3-x_4,\dots) \in \displaystyle \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}R_n
\end{equation}
so that the $i$-th component of $x$ is $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} 2(-1)^{k+1}x_{k} +(-1)^{i+1}x_i$. My question is, is $x$ an element of
\begin{equation}
R=\bigg\{r \in \displaystyle \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}R_n \bigg|r_n=g_{mn}(r_m) \; f\text{or all} \; n \leq m \;\text{in} \; \mathbb{N}\bigg\} 
\end{equation}
which is, by the definition, the inverse limit of $(R_n,g_{mn})$? My intuition is that it shouldn't be but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: You only need to check the given condition (in which $f_{mn}$ should be $g_{mn}$, I guess). Moreover, it's enough to verify $g_{n+1,n}(r_{n+1})=r_n$.

Comment: Thanks @Berci. My worry was the sum that appears in the $i$-th component. As we increase $i$ this sum gets bigger and bigger (in the sense that it has more and more non-zero elements)  and so I wasn't sure if that would cause a problem. But I guess no matter how big $i$ is it is still a natural number and so the sum is finite and then $g_{im}(x_i)$ is always well-defined.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly correct.